# Use TSDist to compare time series accelerometer data

Tags: r, time-series, visualization

I'm trying time series data-sets that contain X,Y,Z data from an accelerometer using TSDist package in R. However, the command returns an error stating that the information is not numeric. All values are stored as num?

```
TSDistances(controlnew, postnew, distance = "cor")
<simpleError in .common.ts.sanity.check(x): Series must be numeric>
[1] NA

controlnew <- as.numeric(controlnew)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I'm just trying to compare the accuracy between two actions as they were measured by a mobile phone.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please let us see what is in your data by typing `dput(controlnew)` and posting the results?